# Wrong HEX value returned in serial communication

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, hex

I am trying to send a `HEX` command to a note validator using rs232 <=> usb cable
My command is: `02 08 10 1F 10 00 03 17`
The reply should be: `02 0B 20 01 00 01 00 03 02 03 2A`
Instead i am getting: `0C FE 86 06 F0 FE or 38 98 86 06 F0 FE`

This appears in any serial program such as `hterm` and `coolterm`.

Trying the code below brings simillar results:

```
import serial
import struct

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate=9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

print(ser.isOpen())
data = '\x02\x08\x10\x1F\x10\x00\x03\x17'


ser.write(data)
s = ser.read(1)
print(s)
ser.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure the baud rate, parity etc are correct? Also calling binary data "HEX" is just confusing.

Comment: bits should be 9600,databits 8 parity:none, stop bits 1 flow: none, as it seems to me reply is much shorter than should be maybe in linux i need to configure USB or something?or perhaps i am sending in a wrong way HEX data?

Comment: What is this `note validator`?

Comment: Its GBA ST2 http://www.microcoin.com/display.asp?entityid=5863

Comment: When sending: `02 08 10 1F 10 00 03 17` it should power up / activate

Comment: I don't think you will get any answers, because it would require for us to read the documentation and reverse engineer what you are trying to do with your command, and then figure out what went wrong on the other side. You should at least give more details about what your command is, and what the returned value means, when interpreted  with the documentation.

Comment: If possible i would hire someone to work on my project (this question above is just the beginning) In windows using the test utility provided once connected tester send the command to "activate" the ST2, while the repy is as mentioned, while under linux i am getting other weird answer